# Question about a CSS about click:hover with text?

Tags: html, css

I need to create a "record store". I'm **very** new to CSS and HTML and hardly know anything in JAVA. This is what I need to create.

When the user hovers over one of these featured records, move that record vertically lower and make it become larger.  Also, display information about that record that was not previously visible.

Any help is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use `:hover`.

Regarding the information you want to display, you could put them in another `div` with `display: none` and change it to `display: block` on hover using something like `#record:hover #content {}`.

```
<div id="record"></div>
```

```
#record {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: grey;
}

#record:hover {
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y5j8rhfL/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
<div class = "record" ></div>
```

Now the HTML is ready

```
.record{
/* Whatever style you've applied here is fine */
transition-duration: .5s;
}
.record:hover{
transform: translateY(15px) scale(1.5);
}
```

The *translateY(15px)* is to move it down by 15px
While the *scale(1.5)* is to make it appear bigger